# CORS Policy Not Working in IdentityServer4

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using IdentityServer4 (IS4) to connect to AzureAD for authentication. I have created the app on AzureAD and used the correct ClientID and Tenant ID as well.

I am getting the following error while signing in:

```
[15:13:04 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler
AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.

[15:13:06 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CORS request made for path: /signin-oidc from origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint

[15:13:06 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in.
```

Please, I requesting to guide me, as in what is going wrong here.

Here's how my entire Startup.cs looks like:

```
// Copyright (c) Brock Allen & Dominick Baier. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See LICENSE in the project root for license information.


using IdentityServer4;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI;
using System.Reflection;
using IdentityServer.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using IdentityServer.Data;
using IdentityServer4.Configuration;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using IdentityServer4.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IdentityServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Environment = environment;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityServerContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly))
);

            services.AddDbContext<Data.ConfigurationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                //New added
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 00);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityServerContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                    // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
                    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Account/Login";
                    options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Account/Logout";
                    options.Authentication = new IdentityServer4.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions()
                    {
                        CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(10), // ID server cookie timeout set to 10 hours
                        CookieSlidingExpiration = true
                    };
                })
                //.AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources, CORS)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseMySql(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseMySql(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                })
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddProfileService<IdentityProfileService>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            var autBuilder = services.AddAuthentication();

            //Azure AD
            autBuilder.AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            /*
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                    // register your IdentityServer with Google at https://console.developers.google.com
                    // enable the Google+ API
                    // set the redirect URI to https://localhost:5001/signin-google
                    options.ClientId = "copy client ID from Google here";
                    options.ClientSecret = "copy client secret from Google here";
                });
            */
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });


        }
    }
}
```

And the Azure Extension.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
{
    public static class AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
    {        
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
            => builder.AddAzureAd(_ => { });

        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
            builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
            return builder;
        }

        private class ConfigureAzureOptions: IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
        {
            private readonly AzureAdOptions _azureOptions;

            public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions)
            {
                _azureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
            }

            public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
                options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            }

            public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the appsettings.json

```
Appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    //"DefaultConnection": "connectiong_string"
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "TimeSettings": {
    "AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime": 15552000,
    "SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime": 1296000,
    "IdentityTokenLifetime": 300,
    "AccessTokenLifetime": 300,
    "AuthorizationCodeLifetime": 300

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer has its own CORS settings for requests made by its clients.

You use the AllowedCorsOrigins collection on the client configuration to set this up. Simply add the origin of the client to the collection and the default configuration in IdentityServer will consult these values to allow cross-origin calls from the origins.

```
new Client
{
    ...
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
    {
         "http://www.myclient.com"
     }
}
```

Hard to tell, one thought is if the use of "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc" should be changed to some other URL to not conflict with other things that uses /signin-oidc.

For example in the code [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Startup.cs)  they use:

.AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Sign-in with Azure AD", options =>
{
...

```
options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

options.ResponseType = "id_token";
options.CallbackPath = "/signin-aad";
options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-aad";
options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-aad";
```

Comment: Hello Tore. thank you so much for responding. Actually I've added the client and the cors into the DB. Please find the screenshots. Clients Table - https://snipboard.io/LMfYDR.jpg     ClientCorgsOrigin table - https://snipboard.io/UGdFSj.jpg I am not able to understand where i am going wrong :(

Comment: Do you get any CORS errrors in the browser console? You are sure the client is not the first one on localhost 5003?  (ClientID 4)?

Comment: Can your post more from our Startup.cs file? (the ConfigureServices method) How do you add AzureAD in that method? I think the problem is that the return URL /signin-oidc might be wrong.

Comment: Yeah. There's an error in the console about favicon - screenshot - https://snipboard.io/ltLwFq.jpg and the properties of ISR - https://snipboard.io/sPur5q.jpg

Comment: yeah. The link to the code - https://vsit.click/we9sb Thank you so much for giving so much time and effort to this.

Comment: Here's the screenshot of callback url on Azure - https://snipboard.io/5AHPWm.jpg

Comment: You don't need to worry about the missing favicon.ico, you can add one if you like.

Comment: Can you add your entire Startup.cs file?

Comment: Hello Tore, I have updated the question with the Startup.cs content. Thank you once again :)

Comment: Hello Tore, Thank you so much :) I am still getting the error.

[18:58:20 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CORS request made for path: /signin-aad from origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint.

I will use the template from the demo repo and update.

Comment: Let me know if it works by using the template.

Comment: Hello Tore. This time it gave a different error message on browser that said - incorrect correlation id. And in the terminal, I got the same error :(  - [15:49:17 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CORS request made for path: /signin-aad from origin: null but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint
[15:49:17 Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler

Comment: Is this error because I am using AdBlocker on my browser? Do you think its a local issue? Issue with my local development env?

Comment: could be adblocker because the origin should not be null, its only null if it is blocker or if it is from a local file opened in your browser.I would explorer  the failing CORS request using a tool like Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler ) and post the request and response in your question.

Comment: also, the /signin-aad is not an IdentityServer ur, its for the OpenIDConnect handler in the authentication middleware. Could be the order where you setup/configre CORS in setup.cs?   try to define CORS first in your configureservices method.

Comment: Got it! It's working now. The Authority url was incorrect. I was passing one without clientID. The following one worked: https://login.microsoftonline.com/[client_id]/v2.0/